# I want to test a single web page's response status of many requests(To find out whether there are 404, 5XX requests of this web page)

Tags: python, http, http-status-code-404

I am new to python, can anyone tell me which python tools I should use to get my work done? Any good idea to build a python script to automatically find out these 404, 5XX requests?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We can check the response status code:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
>>> r.status_code
200
```

Requests also comes with a built-in status code lookup object for easy reference:

```
>>> r.status_code == requests.codes.ok
True
```

If we made a bad request (a 4XX client error or 5XX server error response), we can raise it with `Response.raise_for_status()`:

```
>>> bad_r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/status/404')
>>> bad_r.status_code
404
```

But, since our `status_code` for r was 200, when we call `raise_for_status()` we get:

```
>>> r.raise_for_status()
None
```

Reffer : this [link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes)

Comment: Hi Nilam, there are many requests in the background behind one request. How can I check all the responses status activated by this single request, say:http://hotel.qunar.com/city/beijing_city/dt-18058/?tag=beijing_city#fromDate=2015-04-01&toDate=2015-04-06&q=&from=qunarHotel&fromFocusList=0&filterid=2a0bc6c6-0c93-4341-8362-fe70b43d25e6_A&showMap=0&qptype=&QHFP=ZSS_A38FA3E0

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes check this bro

Comment: Thanks bro, maybe this question didn't mean what I really want to know. So I raise another question. If you have time, could you please take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210116/how-to-get-all-http-requests-if-i-only-visist-www-google-com-so-that-i-can-autom